# Sankalpam for Colombo, Sri Lanka

Tags: sankalpa

I need the sankalpam for Colombo, Sri Lanka.

(I am planning to perform Sandhyavandham and I can't use Bharata Varsha and Bharata Khanda, as it is a different country.)

Comment: Bharatavarshe Bharatakhande Simhaladvipe

Comment: Thanks for the information...but Can you please let me know the complete sankalpam.. .like it comes between which 2 rivers or sea..like that..